# Can the iPhone screen's digitizer be safely separated from the glass?

Tags: iphone, screen, digitizer

I recently broke my iPhone 3G screen. I've had it replaced, and I still have the broken screen. Seems like the digitizer on that screen is fine and could be reused.

I would like to separate the digitizer from the glass and try to do some hacks with it.

Can I use a heat gun to take it apart from the glass, or will this damage the digitizer? Is there another way I can take it off?

Comment: The construction of the iPhone's screen has changed dramatically and repeatedly since the first iPhone in 2007. Knowing which iPhone it is you're talking about would help a lot.

Comment: Just edited the question. It's an 3G. Sorry. I though everybody knows what iPhone I have :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The digitiser is built into the glass with epoxy, so no, there is no way to separate it.

> [We tried](http://guide-images.ifixit.net/igi/kUEKB6Y2Ah5OIfAh.huge). If you look at the lower left corner of the LCD you can see the scarring of our attempts to seperate the LCD from the digitizer.

<sup>Source: [iFixit: Can I separate the glass from the LCD screen?](http://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/25507/Can+I+separate+the+glass+from+the+LCD+screen)</sup>

Comment: I think he wanted to know if you can separate the DIGITIZER from the glass. Your link is about separating the LCD from the glass. Nevertheless it's correct that you cannot do this.

Comment: I just edited my question: the iPhone is an 3G. Maybe it was different back then

Comment: @duci9y is correct that in almost all cases, you will break both the digitizer and the glass due to the strength of the glue and the thinness of each layer. You might be able to separate the pieces, but consider just using what you have for hacking or ordering a digitizer as you wish for hacking if that's the ultimate goal.

Comment: @MaxRied If you had clicked on that link and read it, it is mentioned if you scroll down that the glass and the digitiser are joined with epoxy or an epoxy-like adhesive.
And yes, it was different for the 3G. I will find some info about that.

Comment: Ok I found this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9PKO5nlKo4 and you can clearly see that attempting to do what you want will result in disaster.

Comment: oooow... So the digitizer is glued to the screen on the FULL surface of it. Damn... I thought it's only on the edges...

Comment: Yeah, it’s like the digitiser layer, epoxy layer, and finally the glass. Or maybe the other way round.